# How can I find out why chrome blocks a request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, cross-origin-read-blocking

[image: Google Chrome Devtools showing a blocked request]

I have a tracked down an issue to the point that is clearly related to my request being blocked in the the browser. Is there a way to find out the reason why it got blocked?

It seems to be related to an iFrame, since the the request is only blocked inside the iFrame, but I would like to be able to analyse the details.

Comment: When the browser blocks a request it shows the reason in the console.

Comment: Also clicking on the networked output should give more information.

Comment: The reason generally shown in the console is `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, which provides no additional information, and no the output does not give more information.

Answer (score -2):

1. You can use fiddler or wireshark
   Wireshark
   https://www.wireshark.org/

Fiddler
https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

2. You can use Microsoft ETL Network logs

- Create a folder C:\msfiles
- open an Admin elevated cmd
- issue the command netsh trace start InternetClient_dbg capture = yes maxsize = 450 filemode = circular persistent = yes overwrite = yes traceFile = C:\msfiles\Etl_trace.etl
- do your request
- stop the trace using command netsh trace stop

-> review the Etl_trace.etl

Comment: Wireshark is for analyzing requests.  It does nothing to indicate why Chrome never made a request because it decided to block it.